# Proving $\Im((\tan(\frac{m\pi}{2n+1})+i)^{2n})=\tan(\frac{m\pi}{2n+1})\Re((\tan(\frac{m\pi}{2n+1})+i)^{2n})$ for integers m and n

Tags: solution-verification, complex-numbers

#### Method 1

Let $$\alpha=\frac{m\pi}{2n+1}$$ $m,n \in ℤ$

We have

$$(\tan(\alpha)+i)^{2n+1}=(\frac{\cos(\alpha)-i\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)}i)^{2n+1}=i^{2n+1}(\exp(-i(\frac{m\pi}{2n+1})))^{2n+1}/\cos^{2n+1}(\alpha)$$ $$=i(-1)^{m+n}/\cos^{2n+1}(\alpha)$$

Let $(\tan(\alpha)+i)^{2n}=u+iv$ where $u,v \in ℝ$

Then $(\tan(\alpha)+i)^{2n+1}=(u+iv)(\tan(\alpha)+i)=i(-1)^{m+n}/\cos^{2n+1}(\alpha)$

But $\Re(i(-1)^{m+n}/\cos^{2n+1}(\alpha))=0$ so $\Re((u+iv)(\tan(\alpha)+i))=u\tan(\alpha)-v=0$

Thus, $\Im((\tan(\frac{m\pi}{2n+1})+i)^{2n})=\tan(\frac{m\pi}{2n+1})\Re((\tan(\frac{m\pi}{2n+1})+i)^{2n})$

---

#### Method 2

#### Case 1

For the $n=-1$ case it's easy to check that indeed $$\Im((\tan(\frac{m\pi}{2(-1)+1})+i)^{2(-1)})=\tan(\frac{m\pi}{2(-1)+1})\Re((\tan(\frac{m\pi}{2(-1)+1})+i)^{2(-1)})$$ for any arbitrary integer $m$, as both the LHS and the RHS will be zero

---

#### Case 2

Similarly, in the case where $n=0$ it's trivial to check that the equality holds

---

#### Case 3

Let $z=x+iy$, let $m$ $\in$ $ℤ$ and let $n$ $\in$ $ℤ\setminus \{-1,0\}$

$r=\cos(\theta+2n\theta)=\cos(\theta)\cos(2n\theta)-\sin(\theta)\sin(2n\theta)$ in cartesian form is $(x^2+y^2)^{n+1}=x\Re(z^{2n})-y\Im(z^{2n})$

Let $a$ $\in$ $ℝ$

Now we can investigate the multiplicity of the intersection of $x=ay$ and the curve $r=\cos(\theta+2n\theta)$ at the origin

Substituting $x=ay$ gives us

$$0=y^{2n+1}(\Im((a+i)^{2n})-a\Re((a+i)^{2n})+(a^2+1)^{n+1}y)$$

Given that $n$ $\in$ $ℤ\setminus \{-1,0\}$, it is guaranteed that $r=\cos(\theta+2n\theta)$ defines a rose curve with an odd number of petals

It is a known fact that the singular point of a rose curve with an odd number of petals is ordinary. Thus, if the rose $r=\cos(\theta+2n\theta)$ has $2n+1$ petals then there exist exactly $2n+1$ lines of the form $x=\tan(\frac{m\pi}{2n+1})y$ that intersect the rose curve at the origin with multiplicity $2n+2$

Since $x=\tan(\frac{m\pi}{2n+1})y$ intersects the curve $r=\cos(\theta+2n\theta)$ at the origin with multiplicity $2n+2$, $\Im((a+i)^{2n})-a\Re((a+i)^{2n})$ must be zero if $a=\tan(\frac{m\pi}{2n+1})$

Thus, we have $$\Im((\tan(\frac{m\pi}{2n+1})+i)^{2n})=\tan(\frac{m\pi}{2n+1})\Re((\tan(\frac{m\pi}{2n+1})+i(^{2n})$$

---

Is method 2 valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$a := \cos\frac{m\pi}{2n + 1}, \quad b := \sin\frac{m\pi}{2n + 1}.$$
We have
$$(a \pm \mathrm{i}b)^{2n + 1} = (-1)^m. \tag{1}$$

Let $u, v \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\left(\frac{b}{a} + \mathrm{i}\right)^{2n} = u + \mathrm{i} v.$$
We have
$$\left(\frac{b}{a} + \mathrm{i}\right)^{2n + 1} = \left(u + \mathrm{i} v\right)\left(\frac{b}{a} + \mathrm{i}\right)$$
or
$$\frac{(a - \mathrm{i}b)^{2n + 1}\mathrm{i}^{2n + 1}}{a^{2n + 1}} = \left(\frac{ub}{a} - v\right) + \mathrm{i}\left(\frac{vb}{a} + u\right)$$
or (using (1))
$$\frac{(-1)^m(-1)^n \mathrm{i}}{a^{2n + 1}} = \left(\frac{ub}{a} - v\right) + \mathrm{i}\left(\frac{vb}{a} + u\right)$$
which results in
$$\frac{ub}{a} - v = 0.$$

We are done.